# C++ How to build generic Products in a Factory

Tags: c++, generics

I'm trying to figure out a way to solve the following problem (stripped down version of the actual code, sorry for the obvious memory leaks):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A {
    struct Product {
        virtual void doSomething() const =0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct SpecialProduct : public Product {
        T t;
        SpecialProduct(T t) : t(t) {};
        virtual void doSomething() const { std::cout << "A: " << t << " does something\n"; }
    };

    struct Factory {
        template<typename T>
        Product* create(T t = T()) const { return new SpecialProduct<T>(t); }
    };
}
namespace B {
    struct Product {
        virtual void doSomething() const =0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct SpecialProduct : public Product {
        T t;
        SpecialProduct(T t) : t(t) {};
        virtual void doSomething() const { std::cout << "B: " << t << " does something\n"; }
    };

    struct Factory {
        template<typename T>
        Product* create(T t = T()) const { return new SpecialProduct<T>(t); }
    };
}


struct ProductType { };

template<typename T>
struct SpecialProductType : public ProductType {};

int main() {

    // I have a factory of a known type
    A::Factory f;

    // standard procedure
    A::Product* p = f.create<int>();
    p->doSomething();

    // I have a product type description from some source
    ProductType* t = /* some source */ 0;

    // How do i get a product instance of type t from f?
    // A::Product* p = f. ???
}
```

I have multiple implementations of a module, in this case within different namespaces. The factory pattern is utilized to handle the variants. Each module offers (abstract) Products and specialized generic versions. Product types are represented using a uniform class infrastructure following the same pattern.

My problem is: given a pointer to a specialized product type, how can I implement a function producing an instance of a correspondingly specialized product from a given factory object?

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

After working on it for a few days I came up with the following solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct ProductType {
    type_index type;
    ProductType(type_index type) : type(type) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct SpecialProductType : public ProductType {
    SpecialProductType() : ProductType(typeid(T)) {}
};


template<typename Derived, typename _product_type>
struct FactoryBase {

    typedef _product_type product_type;

    map<type_index, function<product_type*()>> creators;

    template<typename T>
    void addProductType() {
        creators[typeid(T)] = [&]()->product_type* { 
            static_cast<Derived*>(this)->template create<T>(); 
        };
    }

    product_type* createForType(const ProductType& type) {
        return creators[type.type]();
    }
};  


namespace A {
    struct Product {
        virtual void doSomething() const =0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct SpecialProduct : public Product {
        T t;
        SpecialProduct(T t = T()) : t(t) {};
        virtual void doSomething() const { std::cout << "A: " << typeid(T).name() << " does something\n"; }
    };

    struct Factory : public FactoryBase<Factory,Product> {
        typedef Product product_type;
        template<typename T>
        Product* create() const { 
            std::cout << "A is creating a product of type " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
                return new SpecialProduct<T>(); 
        }
    };
}
namespace B {
    struct Product {
        virtual void doSomething() const =0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct SpecialProduct : public Product {
        T t;
        SpecialProduct(T t = T()) : t(t) {};
        virtual void doSomething() const { std::cout << "B: " << typeid(T).name() << " does something\n"; }
    };

    struct Factory : public FactoryBase<Factory,Product> {
        typedef Product product_type;
        template<typename T>
        Product* create() const { 
            std::cout << "B is creating a product of type " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
            return new SpecialProduct<T>(); 
        }
    };
}


int main() {

    // I have a factory of a known type
    A::Factory f;
    f.addProductType<float>();
    f.addProductType<string>();

    ProductType* tf = new SpecialProductType<float>();
    ProductType* ts = new SpecialProductType<string>();

    f.createForType(*tf)->doSomething();
    f.createForType(*ts)->doSomething();
}
```

Essentially I'm building my own dynamic dispatcher table based on the type of product to be created within the FactoryBase class. The key is the generic type, the value a functor capable of creating a proper instance.

The downside of the presented solution is the requirement of registering a list of supported types - but this can be done without altering the code of the factories or the product types  (open/close principle). Any user code can dynamically extend the list of supported product types.